# How to write a mysql procedure to insert data?

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dasd (

IN aSupplierID varchar(4),
IN aSupplierName varchar(100),
IN aSupplierAddress varchar(255),
IN aSupplierTelPhone varchar(10))

BEGIN

insert 
into 
supplier
(SupplierID,SupplierName,SupplierAddress,SupplierTelPhone)
values 
(aSupplierID,aSupplierName,aSupplierAddress,aSupplierTelPhone);

END
```

> I find an error in the line 'values(aSupplierID,aSupplierName,aSupplierAddress,aSupplierTelPhone);
>   END'.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. i think this will help you http://goo.gl/pD3Yx9  and http://goo.gl/K4cqYC

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try following one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dasd (

IN aSupplierID varchar(4),
IN aSupplierName varchar(100),
IN aSupplierAddress varchar(255),
IN aSupplierTelPhone varchar(10))

BEGIN

insert 
into 
supplier
(SupplierID,SupplierName,SupplierAddress,SupplierTelPhone)
values 
(in_aSupplierID,in_aSupplierName,in_aSupplierAddress,in_aSupplierTelPhone);    
END
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the difference between your answer and question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE das1d (

IN aSupplierID VARCHAR(4),
IN aSupplierName VARCHAR(100),
IN aSupplierAddress VARCHAR(255),
IN aSupplierTelPhone VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN

INSERT 
INTO 
supplier
(SupplierID,SupplierName,SupplierAddress,SupplierTelPhone)
VALUES 
(aSupplierID,aSupplierName,aSupplierAddress,aSupplierTelPhone);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The delimiter is changed to $$ to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself. Click [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) for more details about defining stored procs.